# JSON parse variable result

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, output

I have a JSON which I query with xhr. The objects (person) contain a key-value pair called "serviceLevel" that I have to split.

When I stack this in a variable (services) and log it like this:

```js
let main = document.getElementsByTagName('main');

getXHR("GET", './db/orga.json', (success) => {
    format(success)
}, (error) => {
    console.error(error)
});

function format() {
    let people = arguments[0];
    for (let i in people) {
        let person = people[i];
        let services = person.serviceLevel.split(".");
        console.log(services);
  console.log(person.serviceLevel.split("."));

        let idCard = document.createElement('div');
        idCard.id = person.firstName + person.familyName;
        idCard.classList.add('person');
        idCard.innerHTML = "<div class=\"item nom\"><span class=\"prenom\">" + person.firstName + "</span><span class=\"famille\">" + person.familyName + "</span></div>";
        idCard.innerHTML += "<span class=\"job\">" + person.jobTitle_1 + "</span>";
        idCard.innerHTML += "<span class=\"mail\"><a href=\"mailto:" + person.mail + "\">" + person.mail + "</span>";
        idCard.innerHTML += "<span class=\"tel\"><a href=\"tel:" + person.phone_1 + "\">" + person.phone_1 + "</span>";
        idCard.innerHTML += "<span class=\"tel\"><a href=\"tel:" + person.mobile + "\">" + person.mobile + "</span>";

        for (let j in services) {
            let serviceElement = document.getElementById(services[j]);
            if (!serviceElement) {
                let serviceElement = document.createElement('div');
                serviceElement.id = services[j];
                serviceElement.classList.add('n' + j, "service");
                serviceElement.innerHTML = "<span class=\"title\">" + services[j] + "</span>";

                if (j == 0) {
                    if (services[services.length - 1] = j) {
                        serviceElement.appendChild(idCard);
                     main[0].appendChild(serviceElement);
                    }
                } else {
                    let parent = services[j - 1],
                        parentService = document.getElementById(parent);
                    if (services[services.length - 1] = j) {
                        serviceElement.appendChild(idCard);
                    }
                    parentService.appendChild(serviceElement);
                }
            } else {
                serviceElement.appendChild(idCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
const data = [{
  "Tri": "blablablabla, CSMSI.SAFS, n, XXXX, YYYY",
  "Department": "The best department",
  "serviceLevel": "CSMSI.SAFS",
  "organisationLevel": "blablablabla",
  "rang": "n",
  "familyName": "XXXX",
  "firstName": "YYYY",
  "jobTitle_2": "Directeur",
  "jobTitle_1": "Directeur",
  "phone_1": "nn nn nn nn nn",
  "phone_2": "",
  "mobile": "nn nn nn nn nn",
  "mail": "xxxx.yyyy@zzzz.fr",
  "location": "france"
}];

format(data);
```

The results are different:

```
(2) ["CSMSI", "SAFS"]
0: "CSMSI"
1: "SAFS"
length: 2

(2) ["CSMSI", "SAFS"]
0: "CSMSI"
1: "1"
length: 2
```

[image: JavaScript console screenshot]

As we can see, content of "services" are good, but when I extend the tree, the value of the second key value is "1" ... which is a problem. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: You probably (accidentally) change it later in your code.

Comment: After `services` initialization, are you changing `serviceLevel`? Thats is the reasonable cause for this

Comment: i bring you more details after editing. As you can see, i don t change anything on serviceLevel. It s just a display of the 2 values

Comment: can you please add the example object. And working snippet?

Comment: Your second output makes no sense. `(2) ["CSMSI", "SAFS"]` this means second item is `"SAFS"`. My suggestion, add a snapshot of console for better clearity

Comment: ok i ll add a snapshot + json sample but i just copied/pasted results. It makes no sense... that is my problem

Comment: i just copy paste your code and it is working. https://codepen.io/houssein-zouari/pen/jJGgOW @CoStiC please share your code in codepen.

Comment: Are you sure you are not modifying your array somewhere? If this is the only code you're running, it seems to be working

Comment: The code in the question obviously does not have that problem. The screenshot of the console log suggest that you omitted parts of your actual code. Nothing we can do without an [mcve].

Comment: i pasted the whole code... what is really strange is that some datas are ok, some others are like the one i posted...

Comment: i juste changed "services" variable in my code to "person.serviceLevel.split(".")" and the results are now correct!!!! but the code is ugly :(

Comment: Your question especially due to non tracked changes and no answer is eligible for deletion.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I use a for loop with "classical" (i = 0; i < people.length; i++), i don't have the problem....